# Make local TFS build agent to use v14 msbuild tools

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I've got a couple of ASP.NET vNext applications and I want my CI server to also be able to build them. Both my local machine and the CI server are running VS2015 RC. Then we've got VS Online and a local build controller - which is the server mentioned.

However, I cannot get builds going since it seems to be looking for v12 tooling - which does not include anything DNX.

So - building the solution gives:
[image: The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details]

> The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for
>   more details

It *is* installed - since it came with VS2015 RC, AFAIK. So I thought the build template isn't using v14 tooling. I downloaded the Default Git template v12. And indeed it says:

```
<this:Process.BuildProcessVersion>12.0</this:Process.BuildProcessVersion>
```

So I switched that to 14, uploaded template, ran build. Then:

[image: The build controller used for this build does not]

> Exception Message: The build controller used for this build does not
>   support the version of the template file used by the build definition.
>   The version of the template file is 14.0. The maximum supported
>   version for this build controller is 12.0.0.0.

So trying to solve this - got me to this [forum question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/20709365-9baf-45ea-a5fd-c0397577895a/could-visual-studio-2013-support-2012-build-controller-machine?forum=tfsbuild) that states:

> Then, instead of changing the BuildProcessVersion property, you need
>   to change the involved MSBuild version. Open the build process template, find the Run MSBuild for Project activity, change the **ToolPath** property to the 2013 version msbuild

So - I checked out the template - there is no ToolPath version. There is a ToolVersion property however - which I'll try setting to 14:

[image]

In short, my question is: how can I build ASP.NET vNext apps on my build server, that has VS2015RC installed - but is building using v12 tooling?

**UPDATE**

Seems that the problem is not as much in using the wrong tooling, but more in finding/using the correct DNX runtime *while running under a service account* ( which the TFS agent is doing ). I've added an issue for the DNX team: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2239 .

Answer (score 6):

use msbuild parameter /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 ,which can be added in build definition .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - updating the ToolVersion seems more effective.