# Build VS 2015 Solution w/ Unit Tests on TFS 2013 Team Build

Tags: tfs, build, visual-studio-2015

developers are using VS 2015 now but we don't want to upgrade to TFS 2015 on the server.  So trying to have TFS 2013 Update 5 Team Build build our vs 2015 solution w/ unit tests (x64 if that matters).

I tried several things based on other answers (made a new template and changed BuildProcessVersion from 12.0 to 14.0 and added ToolVersion="[14.0]" for RunMSBuild) - but now getting this when I start the team build:

Exception Message: The build controller used for this build does not support the version of the template file used by the build definition. The version of the template file is 14.0. The maximum supported version for this build controller is 12.0.0.0. This build controller must be upgraded to build this version of the template file. (type Exception)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)

---

References:

[TFS Build 2013 - using Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889259/tfs-build-2013-using-visual-studio-2015/32904979#32904979)

[Make local TFS build agent to use v14 msbuild tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067090/make-local-tfs-build-agent-to-use-v14-msbuild-tools)

---

thanks in advance.

----  edit 5/1/2016
in tfs 2013 for the default template, there does not appear to be ToolPath property ... I did update the ToolsVersion...

[image: TFS 2013 build template]

Answer (score 2):

OK - /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 did not work - I had to add /tv:14.0.  So this is what I did:
1. install TFS 2013 & setup build server
2. Install VS 2015
3. Install VS 2013
4. in the team build, use the Default Template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml) and use /tv:14.0 as MS Build arguments

Answer (score 0):

You have to install VS 2015 on the build agent then use `/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0` on your build.

Comment: thank you... yes I did both of those... it says "The maximum supported version for this build controller is 12.0.0.0." - it there some other setting for TFS 2013 build service needed?  this are MSBuild arguments in the build:  /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0;SignAssembly=true;DelaySign=true;AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile="C:\Program Files\MSBuild\MyKeyFile.snk" /tv:14.0

Comment: Have you tried using a newer build template (you may have a couple options).  We built VS2015 projects on TFS 2010 without any problems before updating to TFS 2015.  I also found this post which suggests editing the build template - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20709365-9baf-45ea-a5fd-c0397577895a/could-visual-studio-2013-support-2012-build-controller-machine?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: chief7 thanks for the reply.  I used the default build template for tfs 2013.. it doesn't have a ToolsPath property...I put a screen shot in my original post...

Comment: If changing the build process template didn't help.  I would remove all customizations from the template so you are back to the default template.  Have you tried setting the vs version and removing the tools version?

Comment: thanks - i still had the old one and went back to it - I got farther (at least it downloaded source files) but then I get this error: TF900547: The directory containing the assemblies for the Visual Studio Test Runner is not valid ''.  -- I do not have vs 2013 installed cos when i had both installed on diff server, I got a diff annoying error specified here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2583434  ...

Comment: Glad this fixed the error in your question. If you agree please mark it as the answer.  If you will create a new question for the new error I will assist there as well.

Comment: yes thank you chief7. i am following instructions in the ms connect link above to re-install vs 2013 update 5 again...

Comment: I do not think it is working properly.  It is still using VS 2013 to compile - VS 2015 specific syntax is causing errors, such as: SomeObject?.SomeMethod();   is giving this error:  Invalid expression term '.'  Syntax error, ':' expected   any ideas?

Comment: Looking at log - it is NOT using MSBuild from 14.0 -- CoreCompile:          C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Csc.exe - any ideas?

Comment: OK i had to use /tv:14.0 as MSBuild arguments in the team build... will answer my question...