# What is the easiest way to get TFS 2013 to run unit tests via VS 2015

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

We have Team Foundation Server 2013 installed with Visual Studio Professional 2015 and I've been able to get continuous integration builds working using the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml build process template and the "/tv:14.0" MSBuild argument. However, I can't seem to find a way to tell TFS to use the 2015 Unit Test suite.

This post [Build VS 2015 Solution w/ Unit Tests on TFS 2013 Team Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961103/build-vs-2015-solution-w-unit-tests-on-tfs-2013-team-build) worked around the problem by installing VS 2013 on the build server, but that means that the build server would use the 2013 testing framework rather than the version used by the developer.

Another option is to use an older build process template that uses MSTest, which supports the "ToolPath" parameter, but MSTest appears to be deprecated ([MSTest V2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/06/17/taking-the-mstest-framework-forward-with-mstest-v2/)). BTW, I tried using the MSTest V2 NuGet packages, but that didn't have any effect on the framework used by TFS, which made sense once I thought about it.

I assume that there should be some way to tie in a third-party testing framework, but the examples I've found use the older build process template.

Has anyone else found a solution for this?

Comment: You really should update TFS to 2017...

Comment: Seems you want to use TFS2013 and test Agent 2015. Why you insist on this  combination? Both of still using TFS2013 and test agent / control or update to TFS2015/2017 using web-based build system is a good choice.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT We're just starting to incorporate MS ALM processes. Until recently we've only used TFS for source control, so upgrading wasn't a priority. Now we're trying to use it to also automate builds and run unit tests. Since I was able to figure out a solution for the build side, I was hoping there was a clean workaround for unit testing, at least until we can schedule an upgrade to 2017. BTW, we'd like to migrate to VSTS, but the Basic level doesn't offer Package Management. We use a local NuGet repository to host projects (e.g. models) that we need to share across Team Projects. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you need your test agent or test controller to work with TFS 2013,
>   use [Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48140) and
>   configure the test controller.
>
> *Source Link:* [Install and configure test agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents)

This is the official recommended practices, we don't suggest you to use some third-party testing framework for handling your situation (not sure if there were).

Besides just as *MrHinsh* commented, we encourage you to move to new web-based build system which is more excellent. For the detail benefit of VNext builds, you could refer to this article [Why You Should Switch to Build VNext](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/why-you-should-switch-to-build-vnext)